# Reverse Proxy for a Virtual host

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

Can someone explain me this code with example:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3333/complaints.php
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3333/complaints.php
</VirtualHost>"
```

PS This code is written in the configuration file of the virtual host `soldier.io`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code turns Apache into a proxy server, so Apache answers the request and then gets the resources.

```
  ProxyPreserveHost On
```

When getting the request from the server, Apache adds a header (called X-Forwarded-For)  with the IP address if the requesting IP address. This means an appropriately configured programming can still know the original requesters IP address, and that a proxy is in use.

```
      <Proxy *>
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
      </Proxy>
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:3333/complaints.php
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3333/com
```

These Libes enable Apache to do the prixying, and allow any request to it.  When someone goes to the soldiers.io/ The ProxyPass and related ProxypassReverse lines will connect to port 3333 on the local machine and request the URL complaints.php, which it will thrn return to the client.

(You will find there is a web server of some sort answering in localhost:3333)